# How do I make the black line arch so it hits the pentagon with the right input?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, python-3.9

I'm making a game where the goal is to have the user enter velocity and the angle of a arch so it can hit the pentagon. I need some help on making the black line arch and not go straight once the user enters their input.

```
import turtle as t

t.color('blue')

t.begin_fill()
for _ in range(4):
    t.forward(20)
    t.left(90)
t.end_fill()

t.color('green')
t.forward(65)

t.color('red')

t.begin_fill()
for _ in range(5):
    t.forward(10)
    t.left(74)
t.end_fill()

t.setheading(0)
t.color('green')
t.forward(67)

print("The target is 181.1m away")
v=int(input("What velocity to use (m/s)?:"))
a=int(input("What angle to set (degrees)?:"))

import math
x_speed=v * math.cos(a)

y_speed=v * math.sin(a)

time_step=0.1
gravity=9.806

import turtle
pen=turtle.Turtle()
pen.reset
pen.forward(v*a)
```

This is my code, and I'm pretty sure the last couple of lines need to be changed to help solve my problem. I'm quite new to python and would love some non-passive aggressive help. Thank you.